# run bower install on heroku within a java/play project

Tags: java, heroku, playframework, bower, bower-install

I need to deploy a java/playframework project on heroku.
I'm using bower to install my frontend dependencies such as angular etc.
Is there any way to run bower install with a "non-nodejs" project?

I've tried to run:

```
heroku run bower install
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could combine a buildpack that builds your frontend with your play buildpack using [heroku-buildpack-multi](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi):

```
$ heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi.git
```

From here you will need to create a .buildpacks file which contains the buildpacks you wish to run when you deploy:

```
$ cat .buildpacks
https://github.com/djng/heroku-buildpack-webapp-client.git
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-play
```

I created the [heroku-buildpack-webapp-client](https://github.com/djng/heroku-buildpack-webapp-client) that supports grunt, bower and compass. Maybe you can use this one.

The idea is that your repository contains a `client` folder containing your frontend and a gruntfile for your build process. The gruntfile should build your frontend into a `client/dist` folder.